# GUI на PyQt и логика на C#. Насколько эта связка годится как кросс-платформенная?

Tags: c#, python, gui, qt, pyqt4

GUI на PyQt и логика на C#. Насколько эта связка годится как кросс-платформенная?

Comment: Вроде подводных камней не видно, но подождём веского слова специалистов.

Comment: чем логика на python не устраивает? Получилось бы очень даже кросс-платформенно

Comment: Просто уже процентов 45% логики есть на c# и GUI на WPF(на Mono он небудет работать)

Comment: мб что то вроде этого https://github.com/mono/xwt или http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto. Или выхотите между Qt и с# как можно больше технологий и языков вставить

Comment: Поправьте, если не прав, но когда упоминается шарп в логике, мне кажется, можно почти и не говорить о кроссплатформенности.
ИМХО, если кода немного, я бы переписал на Python и не кипятил себе мозг.

Comment: c# модули неплохо могут исполняться в Mono, проблема только в GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смешивая в одном продукте такой зоопарк технологий в дальнейшем вы рискуете попасть в неприятности при сопровождении, или доработке продукта.

Делайте либо все на python+pyQt, либо на C#+GTK#, либо как вам уже советовали, на C#+XWT